# How can i share an UDP Client betwen Methodes in WPF?

Tags: wpf, udp

Im am kinda new to coding and had a question. When I open up a UDP-CLient by an button clic,k and try to access it from another Method, I just get the Error: The name "server" does not exist in current context.
The name "connected" does not exist in current context.
When I am connected to the server, I dont want to close the connection,and open it up again.
How Can I fix it?What am I missing? Looking forward for help!
I think it is the same problem with the boolean, it doesnt work either.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace WpfApp1
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UdpClient server = new UdpClient();
        Boolean connected = false;
    }

    public void connect_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

           UdpClient server = new UdpClient(ip_box.Text, Convert.ToInt32(port_box.Text));
            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Is anybody there?");
            server.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
            connected = true;
        }

        catch { }
    }

    public void ip_box_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void port_box_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void send_data_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test");

        server.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: About the error - the 'server' variable is not part of the class. You create one instance in the constructor, but it is not stored as field or property and would have got in the hands of the garbage collector if your code has coompiled. In short, add a private UdpClient _server; in your class (the leading underscore is a naming convention for private fields). Also avoid server I/O on the main thread for larger projects.

Comment: Read up on variable scope.  That's where your problem is.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the Help. Iz worked, but made an other error, wich I am showing in an other question :)